# Jsp gets empty when response take more than 2 minute

Tags: jsp

Jsp gets empty when response take more than 2 minute, I am using tomcat 6 (EC2) and struts 1.3, how to resolve the issue

Comment: whether that will reload after response or page will be blank always?

Comment: Not always, for large data which have more than 2 minutes then page gets empty where as query is printing in logger

Comment: How you are loading the query results jsp

Comment: Request goes to struts and get data in action class and then forwarded to jsp page, if data takes more time then page gets blank other wise no issue.

Comment: Use ajax request instead of form submission

Comment: It's not for submission i am using the jsp page for report

Answer (score 0):

**Resolving Using Ajax Function**

> This code should help someone.

This function can help you to resolve the issue 
When Ajax function is called execution of the result is done in a different page and result is placed in div,td,li,etc as you desire..

```
function ajax(x)
{    
   document.getElementById("divresult").innerHTML = "";
   if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
   {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
       xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   }
   else
   {// code for IE6, IE5
       xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }
   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function ()
   {//4=request finished and response is ready,0=request not initialized,1=server connection established,2=request received,3=processing request      status 200=ok,404=page not found
       if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200)
       {
           document.getElementById("divresult").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
           // alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
       }
   }
   xmlhttp.open("GET", "action_page.jsp?q=" + x, true);
   //x is the value you pass to the action page
   xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: We can do it but there will be major change, can we increase response time for jsp page?